# Issues running Karaf Client with Puppet

Tags: osgi, puppet, apache-karaf

I am trying to run a script to install some features using puppet but I am getting a weird error (exactly a `NullPointerException`). However, if I run the script from my user in the machine everything runs correctly. I am using `Apache Karaf` 3.0.0 and `Puppet` 2.7.

My script is pretty simple:

```
#!/bin/bash
####
#### A init script for Karaf
####

# Repos
for REPO in <%= repos.sort.join(' ') %>
do
   /opt/karaf/bin/client -a 8101 -h 127.0.0.1 -v feature:repo-add $REPO
done

# Features
for FEATURE in <%= features.sort.join(' ') %>
do
   /opt/karaf/bin/client -a 8101 -h 127.0.0.1 -v feature:install $FEATURE
done
```

For running it with `Puppet` I am just using the following:

```
exec {
'/opt/karaf/bin/init.sh' :
  user        => 'root',
  path        => ["/usr/bin", "/usr/sbin"],
  logoutput   => true,
  require     => [Service['karaf'],File['/opt/karaf/bin/init.sh']];
}
```

This is the output I get when running `Puppet` in the machine:

```
info: /Stage[main]/Karaf/File[/opt/karaf/bin/init.sh]: Filebucketed /opt/karaf/bin/init.sh to puppet with sum 7687821cc06d43754a4f44aa9b9a69ff
notice: /Stage[main]/Karaf/File[/opt/karaf/bin/init.sh]/content: content changed '{md5}7687821cc06d43754a4f44aa9b9a69ff' to '{md5}6bb98d2e1079c66a7b9e16fff5ec1860'
notice: /Stage[main]/Karaf/Exec[/opt/karaf/bin/init.sh]/returns: 30 [main] INFO org.apache.sshd.common.util.SecurityUtils - BouncyCastle not registered, using the default JCE provider
notice: /Stage[main]/Karaf/Exec[/opt/karaf/bin/init.sh]/returns: 519 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO org.apache.sshd.client.session.ClientSessionImpl - Session created...
notice: /Stage[main]/Karaf/Exec[/opt/karaf/bin/init.sh]/returns: java.lang.NullPointerException
notice: /Stage[main]/Karaf/Exec[/opt/karaf/bin/init.sh]/returns:   at org.apache.karaf.client.Main.main(Main.java:83)
notice: /Stage[main]/Karaf/Exec[/opt/karaf/bin/init.sh]/returns: 20 [main] INFO org.apache.sshd.common.util.SecurityUtils - BouncyCastle not registered, using the default JCE provider
notice: /Stage[main]/Karaf/Exec[/opt/karaf/bin/init.sh]/returns: 386 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO org.apache.sshd.client.session.ClientSessionImpl - Session created...
notice: /Stage[main]/Karaf/Exec[/opt/karaf/bin/init.sh]/returns: java.lang.NullPointerException
notice: /Stage[main]/Karaf/Exec[/opt/karaf/bin/init.sh]/returns:   at org.apache.karaf.client.Main.main(Main.java:83)
notice: /Stage[main]/Karaf/Exec[/opt/karaf/bin/init.sh]/returns: 27 [main] INFO org.apache.sshd.common.util.SecurityUtils - BouncyCastle not registered, using the default JCE provider
notice: /Stage[main]/Karaf/Exec[/opt/karaf/bin/init.sh]/returns: 497 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO org.apache.sshd.client.session.ClientSessionImpl - Session created...
notice: /Stage[main]/Karaf/Exec[/opt/karaf/bin/init.sh]/returns: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

However, if I run it under my user or root:

```
30 [main] INFO org.apache.sshd.common.util.SecurityUtils - BouncyCastle not registered, using the default JCE provider
550 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO org.apache.sshd.client.session.ClientSessionImpl - Session created...
561 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO org.apache.sshd.client.session.ClientSessionImpl - Server version string: SSH-2.0-SSHD-CORE-0.9.0
Logging in as karaf
564 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO org.apache.sshd.client.session.ClientSessionImpl - Received SSH_MSG_KEXINIT
592 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO org.apache.sshd.client.kex.DHG1 - Send SSH_MSG_KEXDH_INIT
602 [pool-2-thread-2] INFO org.apache.sshd.client.kex.DHG1 - Received SSH_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
619 [pool-2-thread-2] WARN org.apache.sshd.client.keyverifier.AcceptAllServerKeyVerifier - Server at /127.0.0.1:8101 presented unverified key:
620 [pool-2-thread-2] INFO org.apache.sshd.client.session.ClientSessionImpl - Received SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS
625 [pool-2-thread-2] INFO org.apache.sshd.client.session.ClientSessionImpl - Send SSH_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST for ssh-userauth
631 [main] INFO org.apache.sshd.client.auth.UserAuthAgent - Send SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_REQUEST for publickey
643 [pool-2-thread-5] INFO org.apache.sshd.client.auth.UserAuthAgent - Received SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_SUCCESS
675 [main] INFO org.apache.sshd.client.channel.ChannelExec - Send SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_OPEN on channel 101
678 [pool-2-thread-2] INFO org.apache.sshd.client.channel.ChannelExec - Send SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_REQUEST exec
Adding feature url mvn:io.hawt/hawtio-karaf/1.2.3/xml/features
936 [pool-2-thread-5] INFO org.apache.sshd.client.channel.ChannelExec - Received SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_REQUEST on channel 101
29 [main] INFO org.apache.sshd.common.util.SecurityUtils - BouncyCastle not registered, using the default JCE provider
539 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO org.apache.sshd.client.session.ClientSessionImpl - Session created...
Logging in as karaf
552 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO org.apache.sshd.client.session.ClientSessionImpl - Server version string: SSH-2.0-SSHD-CORE-0.9.0
554 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO org.apache.sshd.client.session.ClientSessionImpl - Received SSH_MSG_KEXINIT
579 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO org.apache.sshd.client.kex.DHG1 - Send SSH_MSG_KEXDH_INIT
592 [pool-2-thread-2] INFO org.apache.sshd.client.kex.DHG1 - Received SSH_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
609 [pool-2-thread-2] WARN org.apache.sshd.client.keyverifier.AcceptAllServerKeyVerifier - Server at /127.0.0.1:8101 presented unverified key:
609 [pool-2-thread-2] INFO org.apache.sshd.client.session.ClientSessionImpl - Received SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS
615 [pool-2-thread-2] INFO org.apache.sshd.client.session.ClientSessionImpl - Send SSH_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST for ssh-userauth
620 [main] INFO org.apache.sshd.client.auth.UserAuthAgent - Send SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_REQUEST for publickey
631 [pool-2-thread-5] INFO org.apache.sshd.client.auth.UserAuthAgent - Received SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_SUCCESS
668 [main] INFO org.apache.sshd.client.channel.ChannelExec - Send SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_OPEN on channel 101
670 [pool-2-thread-2] INFO org.apache.sshd.client.channel.ChannelExec - Send SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_REQUEST exec
Adding feature url mvn:org.apache.camel.karaf/apache-camel/2.13.0/xml/features
985 [pool-2-thread-5] INFO org.apache.sshd.client.channel.ChannelExec - Received SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_REQUEST on channel 101
27 [main] INFO org.apache.sshd.common.util.SecurityUtils - BouncyCastle not registered, using the default JCE provider
515 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO org.apache.sshd.client.session.ClientSessionImpl - Session created...
526 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO org.apache.sshd.client.session.ClientSessionImpl - Server version string: SSH-2.0-SSHD-CORE-0.9.0
Logging in as karaf
528 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO org.apache.sshd.client.session.ClientSessionImpl - Received SSH_MSG_KEXINIT
553 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO org.apache.sshd.client.kex.DHG1 - Send SSH_MSG_KEXDH_INIT
562 [pool-2-thread-2] INFO org.apache.sshd.client.kex.DHG1 - Received SSH_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
578 [pool-2-thread-2] WARN org.apache.sshd.client.keyverifier.AcceptAllServerKeyVerifier - Server at /127.0.0.1:8101 presented unverified key:
579 [pool-2-thread-2] INFO org.apache.sshd.client.session.ClientSessionImpl - Received SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS
584 [pool-2-thread-2] INFO org.apache.sshd.client.session.ClientSessionImpl - Send SSH_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST for ssh-userauth
590 [main] INFO org.apache.sshd.client.auth.UserAuthAgent - Send SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_REQUEST for publickey
602 [pool-2-thread-5] INFO org.apache.sshd.client.auth.UserAuthAgent - Received SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_SUCCESS
630 [main] INFO org.apache.sshd.client.channel.ChannelExec - Send SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_OPEN on channel 101
632 [pool-2-thread-2] INFO org.apache.sshd.client.channel.ChannelExec - Send SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_REQUEST exec
666 [pool-2-thread-4] INFO org.apache.sshd.client.channel.ChannelExec - Received SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_REQUEST on channel 101
```

Is it `Puppet` doing something I am missing? Is there a bug in client for Karaf 3.0.0? Thanks and sorry for the long post!

Comment: It seems that calling `System.console(..)` when Puppet is running returns null. Do you know a workaround for this?

Comment: It's true, I found the JIRA ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KARAF-2663

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that this got fixed in 3.0.1. See the folllowing Jira report for details:

[client fails with NullPointerException](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KARAF-2663)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know much about puppet. Is puppet trying to grab what karaf client spits out in the console. If so then a null pointer exception is very likely. I haven't figured out a way to capture output from karaf client. [Here's something I posted on SO related to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22438032/cant-capture-apache-karaf-client-output).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have run into the same problem but I have decided to just use plain SSH instead the client. I believe there is a bug in the client (for my scenario) because it seems Puppet doesn't have a console attached when it runs so `System.console(..)` returns `null` and when trying to use it, it throws `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug in Karaf 3.0.0 and it has been fixed in Karaf 3.0.1

Comment: If this is really the solution, please provide more information and possibly a link or citation of some sort.